# What's the meaning of $errors in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to `Laravel` and I wanted to add error validation messages to view and I wonder what is `$errors` variable and how it works behind the scenes. According my research the variable is an instance of `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` but cannot find any further explanation and details about it. Please can you explain or at least give reference to websites that explain it.

Comment: What is your question about exactly? If you search for `laravel` and `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` the first hit is this link https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html

Comment: @dns_nx, well, for example, this code: if(count($errors)>0) where $errors comes from  and how if a user does not pass validation $errors holds and catches those Flash messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation,

**Note: The $errors variable is available in every Laravel view where the `web` middleware is applied. It will simply be an empty instance of ViewErrorBag if no validation errors are present.**

Also note that before now, we had to explicitly define it by calling `Session::get('errors')->all()`.

Read this for more info:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Also, look for these files in your project for more insight.

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php - withErrors() method.
    /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php - handle() method.
```

Note: I am using Laravel 5.6 as at the time of writing.

Comment: look dude, So, the way I understood is the following validate method in controller passes error messages, if any, to ViewErrorBag and then we reference ViewErrorBag with $errors variable Is that correct? Please find time to reply back it is very important for me.

Comment: Yes...because `$error` is an instance of `ViewErrorBag`...By calling the `withError()` method from your controller and passing the `$validator`, you are binding the error messages from the session to the `$error` variable. I added more resources to my answer to aid you. Check it out again. I hope it helps.

Comment: sorry Chukwuemeka, just last thing I promise :), look when we use Session::flash('success', 'Created') or with('success', 'Created') and then redirect to, say, index page. Do we kind of pass "success" into index page like passing data from controller to view this is just an analogy. This is the last I promise :)

Comment: Sorry, I am just seeing this. Yes and No. The commonly used way to pass data from your controller to your view is via `with()`...https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views... `Session::flash()` can be used to store items in the session but according to the documentation, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#flash-data, it is only for the next request. Which means, those items won't be available in subsequent requests. I hope you now understand why I answered Yes and No.

Answer (score 1):

`$errors` in Laravel comes from validation, to further understand about valiation, kindly refer to documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors.

To know how it show on every blade, kindly check your `app/Http/Kernel.php`, there is middleware `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class` and refer to this middleware, you will see these lines:

```
$this->view->share(
    'errors', $request->session()->get('errors') ?: new ViewErrorBag
);
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: sorry dude but I have a question to you. Look when we use Session::flash('success', 'Created') or with('success', 'Created') and then redirect to, say, index page. Do we kind of pass "success" into index page like passing data from controller to view this is just an analogy. Or 'success' is put into DB depending on session driver and then we acces it from DB with Session::has('success','Created') in the view. Please try to reply back it is very important for me

Comment: 'success' is put into session depending your session driver, it's not like passing data from controller to view because you can't access it with variable $success in your blade file.

Comment: ok just imagine my session driver is file then if I use Session::flash('success', 'Created') and then redirect user to index page then will 'success' session be passed into index page and will it mean that index page shares that success session. Secondly, if I use Session::has('success') in the view then will it look for success in a certain file since I am using file as session driver. I hope for your aid

Comment: If you use `Session::has('success')` it will look for session file that you have declared `success` session. Secondly, you can't misinterpret the session is passed into view, but you can understand like this, session is stored into session file, EVERY blade page can access the session file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation,

Note: The $errors variable is available in every Laravel view where the web middleware is applied. It will simply be an empty instance of ViewErrorBag if no validation errors are present.

Also note that before now, we had to explicitly define it by calling Session::get('errors')->all().

Read this for more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Also, look for these files in your project for more insight.

/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php - withErrors() method.
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php - handle() method.
Note: I am using Laravel 5.6 as at the time of writing.